# How to format this CSS syntax to target second child if the second child is an img

Tags: css

[image]

```css
.deco {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}

.pros-cons .column:nth-child(2):is(img) .deco   {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pros-cons">
  <div class="column">
    <p class="deco"></p>
    <figure>
      <img>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.pros-cons .column:nth-child(2):is(img) .deco   {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Hey, I've been trying to target the second class within a nested container to disable the bottom margin ONLY if the second element is an image. What am I doing wrong here, because it doesn't seem to be working? Is this use of multiple pseudo selectors not valid in CSS3? It doesn't work with figure either.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, I haven't had to do this in the past for my other questions, so I didn't know.

Comment: The image is NOT a nth-child(2)....it's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Be aware there is no such thing as `nth-of-class` which I *think* is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I looks like OP is actually trying to style a previous sibling element - which is not possible with CSS. @Devon update your description to use the class names you use in your code, rather than the vague "second class" description. It's unclear what you're actually after.

Comment: I'm trying to target the second child of the .column class, and remove margin(or padding) from the p.deco class IF the second child element is an img or figure. The class names are what I use in my code, and the p.deco is the first child of the div.column.

Comment: You can't do what you want. That's a previous element selector. You would need to put the padding/margin on the `figure` or `img` instead and then remove it from those elements if they *follow* the `.deco` element.

Comment: Yeah, For some reason I can't accept it as an answer.

Comment: You don't accept other question/answers. You upvoted the accepted answer on the duplicate question and you close/remove this question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your response.

Comment: @Devon you don't have to accept it as an answer, since it's only a comment. This question should still be closed, since it is a duplicated of the one I commented with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could better add a padding top to the second child element and remove it if it is an image. Als in your html the second child of .pro-cons is a figure not an image, so I’ve changed that for you.

```
.pro-cons .column:nth-child(2) {
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.pro-cons figure:nth-child(2) {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.deco {
    background-color: red;
}
```